# ExtJs 5.1 - Ext.tree.panel - store from Json-Object derived from unknown xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, extjs

In [ExtJs 5.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) it is possible to create an `Ext.tree.Panel` from a [Json-object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) given that the Json-object uses the **named values** `root` and `children` to declare the nesting, for example:

```
<!-- Example 1 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ext imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
    
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function(){
        
            var normal_store =  {
                root:{
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                        { text: "detention", leaf: true },
                        { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                            { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                            { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
                        ] },
                        { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
                    ]
                }
            };
            console.log(normal_store);
            
            var tree_panel_1 = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                title: 'tree_panel_1',
                store: normal_store,
                rootVisible: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Lets say that I create a **string-variable** from a **xml-file**.
Then from the **string-variable** I create a **Json-object**.

The only thing I know in advance about the **xml-file** is, that it is *valid xml*, but *nothing else* like tag-names and attributes etc..

I can go from the **xml-file** to **string-variable** by using [Jquery](https://jquery.com/).

Likewise I can go from **string-variable** to **Json-object** by using the [Xml-To-Json](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) Library.

Having this **Json-Object** I have tried to populate an **Ext.tree.Panel** in a similar fashion as in **example 1**:

```
<!-- Example 2 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ext imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
    
    <!-- jquery and jsonToXml imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/xmlToJson/jquery.xml2json.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function(){
        
            //i only know that it is valid xml, but nothing about how many tag types, names, attributes etc.
            var xml = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "path/to/varying.xml", async: false}).responseText;
            var json = $.xml2json(xml);
            console.log(json);
            
            var tree_panel_1 = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                title: 'tree_panel_1',
                store: json,
                rootVisible: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

But, it doesn't show the xml as a tree. I also know why:
ExtJs can only generate such a tree if the Json-object uses the **named values** `root` and `children` to identify the nesting level of the tree which is being produced.

So my questions are:

---

### Question 1: Does anyone know wether it is possible to create trees from general Json-objects in ExtJs using Ext-capabilities like Json-Reader etc. pp.?

---

### If Question 1 is negative: Do I have to write the iteration logic over the Json-object and build the Json-object with the proper named values root and children myself to pass them as a store?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to convert the result of `$.xml2json(xml)` (i.e. what you call "general" JSON-object) to JSON object that `Ext.tree.Panel` can understand — a JSON object with `root`, `children` etc. The actual implementation will depend on how your "general" JSON obtained from XML looks like. It will be just a matter of iterating over it and building new JSON. This can be implemented in a custom reader.

Comment: Yes I thought about using reader, but from the api docs I can't deduce how to suit the reader for my needs. Could you help me there?

Comment: Also keep in mind that nothing about the structure of the xml is known. All reader examples assume that the structure of the xml is known in advance.

Comment: Even though the XML is unpredictable you still need to spec/formalise how it is to be visualised as tree. Will the tag names simply become tree node titles? What to do with attributes, CDATA sections etc., how you want them to be displayed in the tree?